# Researching an automobile accident.Wondering if someone can help me as I never studied physics

Tags: everyday-life, collision, inertia

I am trying do some independent research on a recent auto collision where the information released doesn't seem plausible based on the pictures that I have seen of the accidents aftermath.

A 5,500lb(2500kg) vehicle, referred to as "A", with a stated speed of 68mph strikes a vehicle, referred to as "B", weighing 2,657lbs(1,205kg) that turned if front "A". I am wanting to use an estimated speed of 30mph as I do not know if "B" had to come to a complete stop before executing the turn.

After Impact, "A" continued at a forward direction veering at an approximately 10 degree angle to it's stopping point approximately 100 feet past the intersection staying within the lanes of traffic. "B"s direction was changed dramatically traveling at an approximately 85 degrees from it's intended direction to the same direction as "A". "B" came to rest after traveling in it's new direction for approximately 210 feet.

Hopefully, my diagram of the intersection can be seen. Measurements were found using the measurement tool provided while viewing the satellite images. Since I don't have 100% accurate numbers I am just trying to see what is probable and what is not.

[image]

If I am needing to provide any more factors in this calculation, please ask and I will try to provide what information I can. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

There a few things to think about in addition to the physics others have mentioned. It's certainly not inconceivable for a larger vehicle to dramatically alter the trajectory of a lighter, slower-moving vehicle. Imagine a bowling ball moving faster than a billiard ball and they collide at right angles. The billiard ball is definitely going to change direction dramatically. Additionally, here we have drivers who might or might not have hit the brakes. They also may have been jolted and kept their foot on the accelerator. Unlike the bowling ball or billiard ball, the vehicles have extra stores of internal energy that they can release to "change" the physics.

Answer (score 0):

### Rough Approximation

The angles between final trajectories are small enough that we could approximate this as a 1D problem.

Let's assume both vehicles decelerated at $a$ after impact.

$$d_A=\frac{{V_A}^2}{2a}$$
$$d_B=\frac{{V_B}^2}{2a}$$

The final momentum is then:

$$p=M_AV_A+M_BV_B=M_A\sqrt{2d_Aa}+M_B\sqrt{2d_Ba}$$

Conserving momentum:

$$M_AV_{intial}=M_A\sqrt{2d_Aa}+M_B\sqrt{2d_Ba}$$

Plugging in and solving for a yields $5\frac{m}{s^2}$ which is a very reasonable rate to decelerate at. We can also calculate the coefficient of restitution of the collision at 0.8, which while high is not unreasonable.

I find nothing unreasonable about the data given in the question other than taking a turn at 30 mph which seems way too fast.

Answer (score 0):

There is an underlying assumption for the analysis done by ArtifexR, and to some degree in the OP, that this is a classic physics problem. Most importantly, the collision is treated as an elastic collision which then results in straight-line paths for the two vehicles. It would be very interesting to see the skid marks from this one.

At any rate, let's figure that B is turning across traffic, and A comes roaring through. B is hit by A's left front corner a bit forward of center. This spins A CCW, a bit more than 90 degrees. Rebounding from the front of B, A scrubs off its sideways velocity while travelling more or less in the direction of the roadway, until the tires grab hold and it veers to the left, ending up on the left side of the highway. Depending on the exact collision point, the steering wheel may have still been turned left, which would help the process.

Meanwhile, A (with significant left-front damage which causes major drag on that side) is pushed somewhat to its right, then rolls to a stop along the right side of the roadway. Its initial right-hand attitude change is counteracted after some feet by the drag on the left side.

This all seems, more or less, credible, but without seeing the tracks the two vehicles left it's very hard to say if it really works. The point is, though, that there is no reason to think that both vehicles travelled in straight lines after the collision.

Comment: I agree that treating the problem as a classical physics problem is a horrendous simplification. In reality one of the car could have hit a poll or coasted on smoothly rolling tires, so really nearly any answer could be justified. However, no crazy explanations were necessary to explain the final positions, so that definitely show the story is plausible which is all that the OP was asking for.